# Redirecting parked-domain/anything to one file

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I have the domain cotswoldplayers.co.uk parked on cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk and redirected to cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/redirection.htm using cPanel's parked domain tools.
That works ok when people go to www.cotswoldplayers.co.uk but fails if they go to www.cotswoldplayers.co.uk/any-other-link

Is there any way to get www.cotswoldplayers.co.uk/anything-at-all to go to the redirection page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cotswoldplayers.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/redirection.htm  [L]
```

Comment: That's not working as it stands. Everything at cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk redirects as well!!

Comment: Made some bad assumptions with my first answer.  I am still slightly unclear and the last line may need to be an external redirect in the form of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/redirection.htm`

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation!
cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/anything should not be redirected and should just go wherever it points.
cotswoldplayers.co.uk/anything should ALWAYS go to one page - cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/redirection.htm

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted this by using an 'addon' domain instead of a 'parked' domain then setting redirection on the .htaccess file of the addon domain...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cotswoldplayers\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cotswoldplayers\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.cotswoldplayhouse\.co\.uk\/redirection\.htm" [R=301,L]
```